# Excel VBA Macro to filter the file and copy it on new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA programming and trying to write a VBA code in excel This code will filter my file by `Criteria1:="=*001"` and copy all the unique value to new workbook named AV and save it. Now, I also want to copy all the values where `Criteria1:="<>*001"` to new workbook named LC and save it.

Here is the code I found on this website and tried to modified it but not sure how to use `ELSE` for `Criteria1:="<>*001"`.

```
Sub sort()
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim new_book As Workbook
Dim newsheet As Worksheet

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NRM_Homing_Upload")  'Replace the sheet name with the raw data sheet name

    Set newsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TempSheet")

        If newsheet Is Nothing Then
                Worksheets.Add.Name = "TempSheet"
            Else
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TempSheet").Delete
                Worksheets.Add.Name = "TempSheet"
        End If

            .Columns("H").Copy

                With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("cal")
                    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
                    .Columns("H").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
                End With

                        For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TempSheet").Columns("a").Cells
                            i = i + 1
                                If i <> 1 And cell.Value <> "" Then
                                    .AutoFilterMode = False
                                    .Rows(1).AutoFilter field:=8, Criteria1:="=*001"
                                    Set new_book = Workbooks.Add
                                    .UsedRange.Copy
                                    new_book.Sheets(1).Range("a1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
                                    'new_book.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & cell.Value & ".xlsx"
                                    new_book.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Desktop\excel\test\AV.xlsx"
                                    new_book.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
                                    new_book.Save
                                    new_book.Close

                                End If
                        Next cell



                            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TempSheet").Delete
End With

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Do you really want to loop through all the rows in column A of the temp sheet and filter each time a cell <> ""? Or do you just want to filter twice - once for `=*001` and `once for <>*001` and create two workbooks? And how does the `TempSheet` get populated with data? All I see in your code is that you add the sheet, but it never gets data populated.

Comment: What is in worksheet "cal"? why are you copying NRM_Homing_Upload.columns("H")  to cal.columns("A") and then removing duplicates from cal.Columns("H")? when you run your for loop over TempSheet, it looks like you are working with an empty sheet, since you haven't put anything in it yet. Why are you FOR looping through all the cells in TempSheet if you only have two sets of values you are looking for? The way your with statements are, you are autofiltering "NRM_Homing_Upload", not tempsheet, is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: okay - but you only copy column H from `NRM_Homing_Upload` to `TempSheet` to column A. Then you remove duplicates from column H? Do you mean to remove dupes from column A in `TempSheet`. And so your two workbooks will only have 1 column of data each?

Comment: Hi Scott, I want to do exactly what you wrote but I am not sure how to do that. Also, its not "cal" its tempsheet. Sorry forgot to change it. When I run this it does populate the data and save it as AV.xlsx. from the sheet "NRM_Homing_Upload" its filtering the column H based on criteria and copy all the columns from A to S to new workbook with the filtered results.

Comment: Yes it remove dupes from column A in TempSheet

Answer (score 3):

A few things here based on your original question and comments:

1. There is no need to create a temp sheet for this. You can filter the list in place and remove the duplicates after making the new book
2. You don't need to loop through each cell. You can simply `AutoFilter` the data range
3. Since you are making a new book twice, I put that into its own sub (and called it twice) with parameters for the workbook and range to copy and the file name to save.
4. Be mindful when using `On Error Resume Next`. You should avoid it at all costs, but if you absolutely need it (and in some cases you do), make sure to reset the error flagging with `On Error GoTo 0` the moment you have passed any code that requires error suppression. *Note that my refactored code does not include the need to suppress errors.

Here's the refactored code:

```
Sub sort()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Rem Copy Data From NRM_Homing_Upload
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NRM_Homing_Upload")

    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With .Range("A1:H" & lRow)

        .AutoFilter 8, "=*001"

        CopyToNewBook ThisWorkbook, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NRM_Homing_Upload"), .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), "AV"

        .AutoFilter 1, "<>*001"

        CopyToNewBook ThisWorkbook, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NRM_Homing_Upload"), .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), "LC"

    End With

    .AutoFilterMode = False

End With

End Sub

Sub CopyToNewBook(wb As Workbook, ws as Worksheet, rng As Range, sFile As String)

Dim new_book As Workbook
Set new_book = Workbooks.Add

wb.Sheets(ws.name).Range(rng.Address).Copy

With new_book

    With .Sheets(1)

        .Range("a1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
        .UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
        .UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=8, Header:=xlYes

    End With

    .SaveAs Filename:="C:\Desktop\excel\test\" & sFile & ".xlsx"
    .Close

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. I tried this code but its giving a run time error 424 Object required and highlighting the "CopyToNewBook ThisWorkbook, .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy, "AV". I am not sure what am I missing here.

Comment: sorry - I left the `.Copy` command in when setting the range. try now with edited answer.

Comment: Scott, It's still give an error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method and highlights  the wb.Range(rng.Address).Copy

Comment: sorry, off my game a bit @MGoyal. See edited answer again.

Comment: Thanks Scott. It worked perfectly. The only thing I had to change is to delete this line of code .UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=8, Header:=xlYes because the criteria <>001 was returning with only 1 record instead of all 10 records.